# Parse.com, underscore templates, View's model and current user

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am failing to fill my user profile template using `Parse.User.Current()` as my model. Without further ado, here is what I have :

**HTML**

```
  <script type="text/template" id="edit_profile_template">
    <h1><%= _.escape(city) %></h1>
  <script>
```

**JS**
**- From Backbone's router**

```
  new EditProfileView({model: Parse.User.current()});
```

**JS - From EditProfileView**

```
el : "#page_content", 

initialize : function() {
  this.render();
},

render : function() {
  console.log(this.model);
  this.$el.html(_.template($("#edit_profile_template", TEMPLATES).html()));
},
```

`this.model` does contain the current user object, but I get `city is not defined` from the template. Any idea why?

I am using the exact same syntax for our chat application, using a custom `Chat` object instead of `Parse.User`, and it is working flawlessly.

IS there any restriction in using `Parse.User` as a model for my views?

**EDIT**
`TEMPLATES` here is defined as follows at the entry point of my application :

```
  var TEMPLATES = $("#templates", "body");
```

I use it to improve the efficiency of the app, so I don't parse the whole DOM every time I am switching views (that is to say all the time :).

Comment: What is `#page_content`? Why you don't bind your View with template (`#edit_profile_template`)?

Comment: `#page_content` is the HTML container in which I am outputting my template content (the user profile in this case). You can see this in my view's `render()` function. 
I don't  think I can bind my Backbone's View to my template `script` tag, as `el` is supposed to be the element I am creating on the DOM. 
Plus, if I got it right, `text/template` tags are not in the DOM.

Your explanations on why you think I should do this are most welcome. I do believe I haven't fully grasp all Backbone's mechanisms yet.

Comment: In the EditProfileView render function, when you call the template function, what is TEMPLATES that you pass in?

Comment: Thanks for the question, and sorry not to have removed this from my code sample, or explained it. I'll editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it seems as though the data from your model is not being passed into your template.  Try something like this -

```
var tmp = _.template($("#edit_profile_template", TEMPLATES).html());
this.$el.html(tmp(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I think that may work, assuming the model has a key named city

Comment: tmp() is just the underscore template, defined in the first line.  then we pass in your model represented as json as the data paramter

Comment: if that doesn't work, the problem im pretty certain is just the data format of the model...would help to see what console.log(this.model) in your code above outputs

Comment: Yes sorry, I hadn't read properly. 
I think you might be right. Trying right up

Comment: you could do it all in one line too, instead of breaking it out like i did, just doing `this.$el.html(_.template($("#edit_profile_template", TEMPLATES).html(), this.model.toJSON()));` but it starts to get pretty unreadable

Comment: Agreed. This is working, and I had actually done exactly this for the `Chat` part of the app, but just couldn't see it myself. Thanks for helping out. You ended up hours of wandering :) 
You made my day Sir!